# IntroJS Add Directive To Step Markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, intro.js

I am using introJS to have a user guide. I can show various features, however, i want to add a directive to the markup e.g:

```
$scope.IntroOptions = {
    steps: [
        {
            element: "#step1",
            intro: "Click the button: <button my-directive>Test Directive</button>",
            position: 'left'
        }
    ],
```

With the above, i can see the text 'Click the button' plus a default button.

**myDirective.js**

```
var myDirective = function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    console.log('you clicked the directive');
                });
            }
        };
    };

return [myDirective];
```

However, with the above. The `console.log` is never displayed, yet when i inspect the markup, i can see:

```
<button my-directive>Test Directive</button>
```

If i place the directive any where else in my application, the `console.log` is successful.

Comment: Can you put this in a Codepen please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you.

I've tried to implement @S.Klechkovski's solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmqrd9jk/5/), it failed for me. But let anyone experiment with this.

But actually, I've made something you want [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmqrd9jk/7/):

```
function appCtrl($scope, $compile) {

  function onIntroAfterChange(targetElement, scope) {

    angular.element(document.querySelector(".introjs-tooltiptext"))
      .append($compile(
          angular.element(
            "<button my-directive>Test Directive</button>"))
        (scope)).html()
  }

  $scope.onIntroAfterChange = onIntroAfterChange;

  $scope.IntroOptions = {
    steps: [{
      element: "#step1",
      intro: "Click the button:",
      position: 'bottom'
    }]
  };
}
```

(the hint is to use `ng-intro-onAfterChange` to compile there using proper scope)
The bad part is that I've hard-coded the template there.

But you can go further and set the template as an attribute of the element you want to show tooltip on. Had no possibility to access `intro` field of a step. So... Sory for that extreme level of coding pornography [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmqrd9jk/9/) (it seems to be working):

**Full JS:**

```
angular.module("app", ["angular-intro"])
  .directive("myDirective", myDirective)
  .controller("appController", appCtrl);

function myDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        console.log('you clicked the directive');
      });
    }
  };
};



function appCtrl($scope, $compile) {

  function onIntroAfterChange(targetElement, scope) {
    angular.element(document.querySelector(".introjs-tooltiptext"))
      .append($compile(
          angular.element(targetElement).attr("data-template"))
        (scope)).html()
  }

  $scope.onIntroAfterChange = onIntroAfterChange;

  $scope.IntroOptions = {
    steps: [{
      element: "#step1",
      intro: "Click the button:",
      position: 'bottom'
    }]
  };
}
```

**Full HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
  <div ng-intro-options="IntroOptions" ng-intro-autostart="true" ng-intro-onafterchange="onIntroAfterChange">
    <p id="step1" data-template="<button my-directive>Test Directive</button>">
      Text
    </p>
    <button my-directive>Test Directive</button>
```

Note: [here](https://github.com/mendhak/angular-intro.js/issues/69) is the scary tip that you might need to wrap the code inside the `onIntroAfterChange` with `$timeout`. Hope you won't need it

PS: Actually the problem is that we are using IntroJS from AngularJS. Libs have completely different approaches, so mixing them is a pain.

PPS: Hope someone could provide better solution than I did.

PPS: The best solution is too rewrite introJS using Angular directives

Answer (score 0):

Directives are activated when Angular compiles the HTML templates. In this case you need to manually compile the template using the *$compile* service.
Example:

```
var elementToString = function (element) {
    var container = angular.element('p').append(angular.element(element));
    return container.html();
}

var introTemplate = 'Click the button: <button my-directive>Test Directive</button>';
var introContent = $compile(introTemplate)($scope);

$scope.IntroOptions = {
    steps: [
        {
            element: "#step1",
            intro: elementToString(introContent),
            position: 'left'
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: thanks, but how do you use $compile in a controller? $scope.IntroOptions is defiend in Angular Controllers.

Comment: $compile is a service and can be injected also in controllers, but if you follow the best practices you will wrap this in a directive.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If you can provide an example of $compile being used in a controller, im happy to accept. And by this, i dont mean a controller within a directive.

Comment: That's up to you where you will decide to implement the logic. I've already recommended to do that in a directive. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I bet that the button isn't getting compiled by the angular directive.  If you put a breakpoint on the line "element.bind('click', function() {"
it would never be hit.  Can you post more of the code so that we can determine the best way to make it load?